# chariotsolutions phonegap-nfc plugin intent

Tags: android, android-intent, cordova, nfc

I use the phonegap-nfc plugin from chariotsolutions. Reading a NFC tag while the app is running is no problem. I registered the app for intents so it starts when the app is in background and a tag is read. But the NdefListener is not fired. Does anybody know how to get the tag information when the app is started by an intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a [mime type listener](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc#nfcaddmimetypelistener) to get the nfcEvent fired by the intent when the application launches.

You can use the same event handler you are using for the NDEF listener, everything is the same except for the event type. You don't need to specify a mime type.

`nfc.addMimeTypeListener("", app.onNfc, success, failure);`

This is a bit odd, but the way it works because of how events are fired in the plugin implementation.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works. But there is one problem. When I register the listener, the failure callback is called with message "Invalid MIME Type". But everything works, even with this error. Is this a bug?

Comment: To avoid the error pass in a valid mime type like "text/bogus", or since things are working OK, you could omit the success and failure callbacks. It's not a great solution, but it works around a design flaw.

Answer (score -1):

That plugin listens for NFC events, but it only notifies the JS callbacks that have been previously registered from Javascript code. So your web page must have been loaded in the webview first, then cordova's load event must have been fired, and only then you can register callbacks. So I think the plugin alone does not solve your problem.

To do what you need, you could add NFC detection capabilities to the Web Activity (using Java API), then store the readed tag info in persistence (again using Java), and then create a custom Cordova plugin to read this info from javascript in your JS entry point (for instance in the "deviceready" event callback).

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean with "add NFC detection capabilities to the Web Activity"? What is the Web Activity and where do I have to add it? I'm quite new to this.

Comment: The WebActivity is your class extending CordovaActivity. It contains a webview where your web page is loaded. You can add NFC capabilities to your app so that your activity is opened when a tag is readed. But you'll had to do it the regular way (as if you were developing a non-web Android app). It's going to be tricky to get it working. For more info read [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html)

Comment: The plugin does what you need, you don't need to modify the native code. See my answer.

Comment: @doncoleman My mistake, I thought the OP was asking about starting the activity when it was closed instead of being in the background.