# Is posible to read a NFC tag while the app is closed? - chariotsolutions phonegap-nfc plugin

Tags: android, cordova, tags, nfc

I'm building an Android app with Cordova. I'm also using the chariotsolutions phonegap-nfc plugin, to read NFC/NDEF tags.

My app opens when I pass a tag but don't read the content, because the listeners aren't set already, so I want to know if doing some modification or something to the plugin, is posible to send the data and read it on the first tag passing.

I found this article where it explains how to do it while the app is in background. My app already do this, when is running it cames from background and read the tag. In my case is when the app is totally close, not in background.

Similar article: [chariotsolutions phonegap-nfc plugin intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059763/chariotsolutions-phonegap-nfc-plugin-intent)

I'd appreciate some help with this one, or any directions about it.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible to launch a Cordova app with a NFC tag and process the NFC tag contents in your app.

See this sample project https://github.com/don/nfc-launch

There's an intent filter in AndroidManifest.xml for the NFC tag to launch the app. There's nfc.addMimeTypeListener in index.js to process the tag. See the README and comments in index.js for more info.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I run the sample but it doesn't even start the app when i read a tag. I think I didn't explained well. My app already opens when I read a tag (with the app being closed/not running). I want to know, if using the phonegap-nfc plugin is posible to run the app (being closed) and when it runs without passing the tag again, read the contents.

Comment: Yes it is possible. My example https://github.com/don/nfc-launch demonstrates how to launch the app AND read the tag. The sample app only launches with a URI tag containing http://example.com/foo, you need to adjust the code to launch with your tags. The nfc.addMimeTypeListener is responsible for reading the data from the intent that launched the app.